# Trying to access array offset on value of type int when upgrade PHP 7.3 to 7.4

Tags: php, laravel-8, php-7.4

Recently i updated my laravel 8 project from PHP 7.3 to PHP 7.4 and i am facing this error Trying to access array offset on value of type int.
My team coded in this way.

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)->get();
$id = $user[0]['id'];
```

I know it should be like this

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
$id = $user->id;
```

I know in PHP 7.4 we can not access non arrays like this but is there any way that i able to allow $user[0]['id'] without changing my code because at many places this code exists and i can not change everywhere.
Please help and give your suggestions

Comment: The error means that `$user[0]` is an integer, not an array. That code should never have worked. I think the upgrade just changed the error reporting default.

Comment: It could mean that `$user` is int. Maybe `$id` is malformed or no such user. The first seem reasonable.